# How to avoid rewriting lines to generate code blocks

Tags: environments

I have the following lines :

```
\scriptsize
\begin{Shaded}
\lstset{language=C++,
                keywordstyle=\color{blue},
                stringstyle=\color{red},
                commentstyle=\color{green},
                morecomment=[l][\color{magenta}]{\#}
}
\begin{lstlisting}[frame=none]
    int main(){
        some_cpp_code
    }
\end{lstlisting}
\end{Shaded}
\normalsize
```

which I used to generate a block of `c++` code lines. But this lines of latex codes should be repeated, because I need those blocks to be frequently used.

So what I would like to do is as follows:

**First define a 'class-like'** lines before the document.

```
Latex_class Code_block

\scriptsize
\begin{Shaded}
\lstset{language=C++,
                keywordstyle=\color{blue},
                stringstyle=\color{red},
                commentstyle=\color{green},
                morecomment=[l][\color{magenta}]{\#}
}
\begin{lstlisting}[frame=none]
   ....
\end{lstlisting}
\end{Shaded}
\normalsize
```

**then use the class** to avoid repetition of those lines:

```
\begin{Code_block}
    int main(){
        some_cpp_code
    }
\end{Code_block}
```

But I'm wondering if there is any way to do so. Any help will be appreciated.

---

### Edited

I used `Shaded` environment as follows

```
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{RGB}{248,248,248}
\newenvironment{Shaded}{\begin{snugshade}}{\end{snugshade}}
```

Comment: In which package is `Shaded` defined? Please add a compilable example.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Listings has build in tools for generation code environments, see also the tcolobox package for even more stuff for colored code environments